# Browser timeout when trying to fetch a React Library (using Vite)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I have installed `react-csv` using `npm i react-csv` it appears in my package.json file. When I try and import a component from the library there are no errors.

When I run my app though I get this error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-csv.js?v=47f391bb net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout
```

This suggest that it can't find it. I had a look in the deps folder of `.vite` and it seems like `react-csv.js` is not in there...

There isa `react-csv` folder inside my `node_modules`.

Unsure how to wire it up to vite properly.

I am running react with vite and typescript.

May be a vite issue: https://github.com/react-csv/react-csv/issues/268

Comment: You can try clearing the `node_modules/.vite` folder

Comment: Then do i rerun anything? Or just npm run dev